# server reboot has caused django project to lose directories

Tags: django

A fully functional Django project as well as a couple in development have all broken following the rebooting of the server.

In addition to some pieces of the Django admin returning errors as well as missing .js and .css files, I'm getting errors like this when viewing pages that include images uploaded through the admin.

```
Exception Type: TemplateSyntaxError
Exception Value: 
Caught an exception while rendering: (2, 'No such file or directory')
Exception Location: /usr/lib/pymodules/python2.6/django/template/debug.py in render_node, line 81
Python Executable: /usr/bin/python
Python Version: 2.6.4
```

So did the reboot stomp on some part of my configuration/setup or did it fail to restart a critical piece?

Answer (score 0):

Boneheaded move on my part. Was using sshfs in order for django on one server to read/write files on another server. Should have set up an init script to re-establish this connection on reboot.